# How Are Responsive Images Handled In Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

What is already in place to handle the use of responsive images?

Is there any internal or external library pulled in to handle this? Whether it's srcset / picture... etc? Or would we be coding from scratch or finding our own dependency?

I can't imagine Magento are not aware of this and haven't attempted to solve it (when they have lib-clearfix, etc).

Comment: Please provide more information to clarify your requirements.

Comment: If Magento 2 has any internal method for handling multiple versions or responsive images or whether the behaviour would have to be manually added despite being a problem on nearly every website...

Comment: From what I understand is the original poster is looking for the ability to add multiple resized images for say the product listing or even  when referencing something from media serving the best  suited image for the device.

Comment: For the record if you need to resize a catalog product image you can use the in built helper
 $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($_product, 'category_page_grid_responsive')->getUrl();
category_page_grid_responsive refers to the image id  I've set in my view.xml

Comment: Why has this question been closed as "unclear"? The question cannot be more clear than that. And it seems Magento 2.x does indeed **not** have anything in place to render responsive images.

Comment: I disagreed with the code of conduct so I was banned and censored, they then went after all of my other questions and downvoted me because they disagreed with me.

Hope that answers your question.